# Is $\Bbb Q$ disconnected under general topology from $\Bbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

I just completed the proof of that fact that $\Bbb Q$ is disconnected. My question is how to find a separation of $\Bbb Q$.

Let $X$ be a topological space. We say $A$ and $B$ forms a separation of $X$ if $A\cap \bar{B}$ and $\bar{A}\cap B$ are empty and $A\cup B=X$.

Here $\Bbb Q$ denotes the set of rational numbers.

Can someone please help with hints.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are missing some properties... “two subsets which are disjoint from each other[‘s] closure” is surely not enough, or else $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ would have given you an answer. Perhaps start by having the correct definition of “separated”.

Comment: Please see the edit. @arturo

Comment: As a hint, the real numbers $\mathbb R$ are *connected* and do not have the kind of "separation" you seek for $\mathbb Q$.  So the crux of the "separation" involves picking an *irrational* number (to split the rationals).

Comment: @hardmath I tried something like $(-\infty,\sqrt{2})\cup (\sqrt{2}, \infty)$

Comment: Yes, that is the classic example!

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Please correct your question (definition of "separated"). In this way it's bad English and not understandable. Thanks.

Comment: @amsmath please have a look.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Ok, then your solution is correct.

Answer (score 3):

$U= (-\infty, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ as the intersection of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ (definition of subspace topology) and similarly $V=(\sqrt{2}, +\infty) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is also open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

As $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ we have $\mathbb{Q} = U \cup V$ and $\overline{U} = U$ (closure in $\mathbb{Q}$) and $\overline{V}=V$ and clearly $U \cap V=\emptyset$, so $\{U,V\}$ forms a separation of $\mathbb{Q}$.